# How to remove wonderlandads from ubuntu chrome and firefox

Tags: malware

I have been experiencing this problem for quite some time now. Whenever I open any site in chrome/FF and click on any link on it, it opens a fresh tab in chrome and with a URL `http://wonderlandads.com/afu.php?zoneid=437742` and it randomly redirects to some websites.

I have this problem with my windows machine as well as ubuntu. My thinking till date was ubuntu is immune to viruses. But this is really annoying.

I searched in the internet for long hours to find a solution. Removed chrome extensions, reset browser and my router multiple times. But the problem still persists. I have seen some solutions online for windows but not for ubuntu eg [here](http://www.freefixer.com/b/remove-wonderlandads-com-pop-up-ads/).

Can somebody point me in some direction so that I can go and figure out a solution for my issue.

I am pretty much fed up with this. When I browse behind a Firewall protected network this issue is not present.

Comment: " My thinking till date was ubuntu is immune to viruses." 1. Not immune but far more difficult than with another OS; at the moment there are zero virusses in the world that left a lab evironments.  2. this is not a virus; it is something you install yourself.  Check /etc/hosts for this. Also check if the binary for firefox and chrome is the same. Update locatedb and do a locate on "wonderlandads".

Comment: and please tell us also what software you installed that got you this.

Comment: I tried to locate `wonderlandads` and checked in `/etc/hosts`. Did not find any traces there. I don't remember what exactly created this problem. But it happens on this very page when i click on any link. I removed all the extensions in `chrome/FF` but its still giving me headache

Comment: Have a look at this work in progress: http://askubuntu.com/questions/826801/chinese-character-folder-created-at-startup/826812#826812

Comment: wonderlandads is a toolbar in a browser it seems.And can have the following names: babylon toolbar, coolcake, search product by conduit. This might work: http://www.virusresearch.org/remove-wonderlandads-com-pop-up-ads-chrome-firefox-ie/#uninstall

Comment: Does this occur only for your device or other devices in your house,too ?

Comment: Also check your router.

Comment: @Serg: It happens on my windows 8 desktop, ubuntu 14 and android phone. For my windows I have kaspersky internet security latest. But still this redirect happens in windows.

Comment: @zamil it's likely that you've got someone tampering with your router. I've seen it done before. People don't typically change router admin password so it's an easy attack vector for hackers. I suggest you change router settings or ask your ISP to do that